# Does Facebook still have a place for favourite quotes and music and if yes how do you edit them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

In the past Facebook had a place where one can specify their favorite music, films, quotes etc. Do they still have this? If yes how can I edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called your about tab, or just "about" on your Facebook timeline. If you are logged in, go to your own timeline, press about and edit what sections to show and what to show in either section by pressing the pen icon.

Comment: You need to scroll to the bottom of the about section and click "see all"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its still there, its now in the "**About**" section of the profile page under the "**Details About You**" sub-heading. To edit it, if you hover over the quotes section, an edit link should appear at the top right, simply click it to edit the section.

Answer (score 1):

You can see and edit it if you are using desktop.. or open facebook website.. it doesn't work on the facebook app..

Answer (score -1):

No. It limits you to 100 characters.

Answer (score -2):

In the Apple App you can do it this way.

- Log in, choose the down arrow beside your name at the top right, then select "Settings".
- Scroll down to the section "Your Facebook information" and choose "Access your information", then "Profile information" on the next screen.
- Then choose "Your contact details" and you should find it after "Life events".

If it isn't there, check if you didn't choose "About you", which looks very similar but annoyingly is missing the section you want - why do they write it this way?